# Multi-Tenant Teams App requires admin approval in tenant 2 but not tenant 1

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, azure-app-registration

I have developed a multi-tenant Microsoft Teams tab app that is registered in Tenant 1 (where it was initially created). Interestingly, the app doesn't require admin approval in Tenant 1, but it does require admin approval when deployed to Tenant 2. I'm trying to figure out why this is happening, as I need to distribute this app across multiple tenants without requiring admin approval each time.

The app was registered using a multi-tenant Azure AD app registration. I have registered a verified domain and updated all references in my code from '/(my domain ID)' to '/common'.

The permission scopes I'm using are:

"User.Read",

"AppCatalog.Read.All",

"User.ReadBasic.All",

"Calendars.ReadWrite",

"OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite",

"People.Read".

In Tenant 2, I have ensured that the setting 'All users can consent for any app to access the organisation's data' is enabled.

Despite these settings, the app still requires admin approval when deployed to Tenant 2. Am I missing something in my configuration? Are there other factors that could cause the app to require admin approval in Tenant 2 but not in Tenant 1? Any suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tracking the question from here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1342935/multi-tenant-teams-app-requires-admin-approval-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I got the same error:

[image]

I created an  **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application and added API permissions**  like below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Global Administrator have not granted admin consent or if the tenant has some policies applied.

You can sign-in as Global Admin grant  **tenant-wide admin consent**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/
organizations/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

[image]

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Applications -> Consent and Permissions -> User consent setting*

Enable the option to  **`Allow user consent for apps`**  like below:

[image]

Make sure Assignment required setting is set as  **`NO`**

[image]

***If still the issue persists,***  try adding verified publisher MPN ID to the Azure AD Multi-Tenant application.

[image]

I am able to sign-in to the application using other tenant user successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Turns out it was because it needed the MPN ID which comes with it's own set of problems for us as this was all built on a development tenant and the domain linked with the MPN ID is a domain from our business tenant and we can't host the identity json as we're using webflow. So its a matter of either moving the Azure AD App Registration to our business tenant or moving away from webflow so we can host the identity json and verify out business domain in the development tenant.